# Pseudoreplication & mixed effects with highly unbalanced dataset

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, mixed-model, independence

I have a dataset with ~250 data points. When I regress Y on X1 and X2, X1 is a significant predictor of Y. However, about half the 250 points are pseudoreplicated; they come from locations with >1 observation and are not strictly independent.

Normally, I would include a random slope for X1 and X2, but the half of the data that come from sites with just 1 replicate preclude that possibility. 
If I do the brute force approach of averaging Ys and Xs within sites, sample size is crushed and the effect is gone. Am I just out of luck without more data, or do I have any more options I haven't uncovered?

Comment: This sentence: "Normally, I would include a random slope for X1 and X2, but the half of the data that come from sites with just 1 replicate preclude that possibility" is unclear. Why can't you do `Y~X1+X2+(1|Site)`?

Comment: Because there are so many sites with only one replicate. And several others with just two or three. My understanding is that it is impossible to accurately compute the random effects (and specifically their variances) with such low within-site replication. Right?

Comment: Hmm. Can you clarify what your X1 and X2 are? Are they categorical or continuous?

Comment: Sure. Everything is continuous.
Y is mammal population trajectories. X1 and X2 are characteristics of the parks the mammals are in.